# Exception when saving an object with related object EF 3.5

Tags: entity-framework

I get an error telling me that: "The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null." when I try to save an object with related object.
Here's my code:

```
public partial class Cat{
    public bool Save()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new PhonebookEntities())
            {
                if (this.ParentCat != null)
                {
                    if (this.ParentCat.CategoryID == 0)
                        context.AddToCats(this.ParentCat);
                }
                context.AddToCats(this);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

And here I create a Cat object and connect it to a relatet parent Cat object and then call the save method:

```
        var cat = new Cat()
        {
            CatName = "Test",
            ParentCat = Cat.GetById(1)
        };
        cat.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess - the `Cat.GetById(1)` looks like:

```
public static Cat GetById(int id)
{
     using (var context = new PhonebookEntities())
     {
          return context.Cats.Single(c => c.Id == id);
     }
}
```

You are using two different contexts - that is the source of the issue. The first context loads the Cat and fills it `EntityKey` but the second context doesn't know this instance so once you call `AddToCats` it will add both new `Cat` and `ParentCat` as well but it fails because new entity cannot have filled `EntityKey` (I know that it is not a new entity but for the new instance of the context it is!).

`Add` based operations always add all unknown entities in the object graph. The entity is known by the context only if the same context loaded the entity or if you called `.Attach` for that entity.

Because of that, this is also incorrect:

```
if (this.ParentCat != null)
{
     if (this.ParentCat.CategoryID == 0)
         context.AddToCats(this.ParentCat);
}
```

Unknown `ParentCat` will be added automatically together with the current `Cat`. If you call this it will also add the current `Cat` but the next call will try to add it again => you will probably get an exception.

This whole can be solved by two ways:

- Load the `ParentCat` on the same context instance as you save `Cat`
- Don't load the `ParentCat` and either use dummy class or try to set `EntityKey`

Dummy class approach:

```
var parentCat = new Cat() { Id = 1 };
context.Cats.Attach(parentCat); // Use correct entity set name
var cat = new Cat()
{
    CatName = "Test",
    ParentCat = parentCat
};
cat.Save();
```

`EntityKey` aproach (this is more like a guess):

```
var cat = new Cat()
{
    CatName = "Test",
    // I hope ParentCatReference will be initialized
    ParentCatReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("Cats", "Id", 1) // Use correct entity set name
};
cat.Save();
```

Comment: Thnx for the help, I got it sorted it out now :)